# Simple UIAlertView app fail on ios 5.0.1

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm currently using Cycript to pop up a springboard alert window like:

```
#!/usr/bin/cycript -p SpringBoard
var message = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
message.title = "Title";
message.message = "Message";
[message addButtonWithTitle:@"Dismiss"];

[message show];
```

But I'd like to get away from this method since Cycript isnt meant for production.

Using theos, i made a tool project and my main.mm is:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Start");

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"1");
        [alert setTitle:@"Title"];
        NSLog(@"2");
        [alert setMessage:@"Message"];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Dismiss"];
        [alert show];
        [pool release];
        return 0;
}
```

Makefile is:

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TOOL_NAME = cmdWindow
cmdWindow_FILES = main.mm
cmdWindow_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit Foundation

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tool.mk
```

it compiles fine, but when i run it on my iphone, i see:

```
iPhone:/tmp root# ./cmdWindow 
2012-03-25 06:33:18.801 cmdWindow[2845:707] Start
2012-03-25 06:33:18.851 cmdWindow[2845:707] 1
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Any Ideas why this is crashing ?  Is it because there's no logic to hook the command line tool to springboard (like the -p  switch of cycript) ?

I've tried both rpetrich and my own custom 5.0.1 headers in /opt/theos/include - same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't show an alert or any UI until you have a runloop spun up and `UIApplication` bootstrapped. Do both of those things from an application properly registered and launched from SpringBoard and your alert will show.

Alternatively, have SpringBoard show the alert on your behalf using the `CFUserNotification` family of APIs.